# Resharper - Fonts and Colors settings not working

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2013

I just installed VS2013 and Resharper. I am trying to change the color of specific types of items (like enums and delegates) from the `Options|Environment|Fonts and Colors` menu. However, when I try to change the Resharper's own items ("Resharper Enum Identifier" for example), they don't work. Changing them doesn't change the color in the editor. However, I noticed that some of the Resharpers items do work (for example, "Resharper Todo Item" works but anything else I've tried doesn't).

Does anybody know what could cause this? I have tried to delete the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\FontAndColors\Cache` registry, but that didn't fix this problem.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Okay, it seems like I had to enable Resharper coloring from "Resharper|Options|Code Inspection|Settings|Color identifiers". Works now!

Comment: I couldn't find why it suddenly stopped working after updating resharper to newer one. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get it working without enabling ReSharper's own identifier colouring.

Try this: http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/26859128-ReSharper-Fonts-Colors-settings-do-not-appear-in-Visual-Studio-after-installation

Comment: Not sure I understand steps 2 and 3 on that page. I create a text file called "extensions.configurationchanged" and type something in the file?

Comment: Yep. The instructions just say to type anything in. It doesn't matter what. Visual Studio is just looking for the existence of the file, and checking its timestamp.

Comment: Any idea what that workaround is supposed to do?  It doesn't actually work for me... my problem is that R# isn't obeying the individual colors set for to-do items... they all generically get colored from the VS options

Comment: The colours for to-do items are a bit different, annoyingly. The colours you set in the ReSharper options are the colours shown in the to-do explorer, not in the editor. The editor always uses the default set in the VS Fonts + Colours options. I'm not sure why, but I think it's because the ReSharper items can be added dynamically, while the VS colours are added statically at install time, so it can't work for multiple to-do types.